# Need advice to cleanup and rectify shading issues caused by boolean

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, shaders, sculpting

[image]

Need advice. I used union boolean to make this object, now need help to cleanup and rectify shading issues. Thank you

Comment: I guess you'll have to do it manually, but you should simplify your mesh a bit, you don't need so many edge loops

Answer (score 0):

I can only reccomend the tutorials from Josh Gambrell. All of his youtube channel is basically about booleans and how to clean them up.

https://www.youtube.com/c/JoshGambrell